# Xcode / Swift: No such module 'GeoFire'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, geofire

I have downloaded latest GeoFire framework v1.1.3 from [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/releases) 
and dropped it in my Swift Xcode project but my `import GeoFire` statement is throwing

> No such module 'GeoFire'

This is very strange because a few minutes ago I did the same for Firebase framework and it is working fine. My target is iOS 8.0 and I believe I do not need Bridging header.

Framework is present in **linked frameworks and libraries** , **Embedded Binaries** and **link binary with libraries**.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use cocoapods. No more headache, just add `pod 'GeoFire'` to Podfile, print `pod install` in terminal and use it in code.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just don't like to use cocoa pods and complicate workspace etc. I prefer to add frameworks manually and feel I have more control over things that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing this in swift (its in your tags) you'll need to create a Bridging Header file to be able to expose the Objective C library to your swift code, importing the objective c library in the bridging header fie. [Here's a guide on how to do this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: But how come Firebase library works without bridging? It is also written in ObjC

Comment: I can only asume that you are not referencing it from your swift code, hence there's no need for it =)

Comment: Eventually I had to do bridging header as you says and of course it works then. I guess there is some difference between Firebase and GeoFire frameworks after all.

Comment: @Kashif Can you provide the code for your bridge please? I've got the same problem but when I import GeoFire Framework, I don't get the prompt to create the bridge file. Thanks

Comment: @Septronic: 
`#ifndef Bridge_h
#define Bridge_h
#import "GeoFire.h"
#import "Firebase.h"
#endif`

Comment: @Kashif Thanks for the code. Did you use the framework that GeoFire project builds? I cloned the GeoFire git, and inside there is an xcode project. When you build the framework target, it creates a framework. I then imported the framework, but xcode is not recognising it. I tried using your code as well as importing the headers as #import <GeoFire/GeoFire.h> but still I get the same error.

Comment: @Septronic: Make sure your bridge is properly configured in build settings and -ObJC linker flag exists there. This mostly happens when the bridge path is not being recognized.

Comment: @Kashif Thanks for the help. That didn't work either, but I ended up importing the entire GeoFire folder (without compiling it into a framework), and thanks to Xcode (importing the files separately finally prompted me to create the bridge for them), and changing the #import <....> in the imported files to #import "..." finally got everything working. I will create this as an issue in the git at some point. If you think it's a good idea to post my finding as an answer here, let me know and I'll do it :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try do it: https://youtu.be/009UrLVlAbo?t=67 but just change the import header file like this:

```
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
#import <GeoFire/GeoFire.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 7.2, with Swift, and ran into this same issue when mixing Firebase and Google Analytics pods.

Firebase alone works fine with "use_frameworks!" in the Podfile, but Google Analytics pod install needs that line commented out. So bridging header file is needed.